# Using SAS: Sample Size Estimation for Percentages - Difference Between Two Estimates

Tags: sas

I work in direct marketing analytics and I have been using a free app called "Plan-alyser"  to determine if the required sample sizes  needed to ensure a pre-specified difference between two test response rates can be considered significant.  Going forward I would like to use SAS to determine this.

Plan-alyser asks the user to input the required information:

1. Estimated response rate for the control panel.
2. Estimated response rate for the test panel
3. The Condidence level

How would I replicate this in SAS so I get an output which would determine a value for:
1. The control and test panel sample sizes required for the conditions listed above.
2. The percentage point difference in response  that is considered significant

Is there a "Proc" or something else in SAS that will give me this desired output?

any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a formula, solving the chi square (or whatever test you use) formula for N instead of for p?

Comment: As the commenter noted, this isn't a programming question.  

Here is a good article to get you started http://www.osra.org/itlpj/bartlettkotrlikhiggins.pdf .  

You should have someone on staff with a strong statistical background if you are developing survey and sample methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Look at PROC POWER with the TWOSAMPLEFREQ statement to calculate the sample size